# getIntent().getStringArrayExtra() always returning null

Tags: android, android-intent

I've been looking for hours but can't seem to figure out what is going on here.  I want to pass an array upon a button press through an intent.  In Activity A I have (in the onclick listener)

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), classB);
i.putExtra("string",stringArray);
startActivity(i);
```

and in Activity B I have in the onCreate method

```
final String theList[] = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("string");
```

whenever I attempt to access the array theList as follows

```
textView.setText(theList[0]);
```

the program force closes and I can't seem to understand why... I feel like I must be missing somthing blatantly obvious but after hours I can't seem to understand why theList = null.

Thank you and sorry for asking what seems to be a repetitive question.

logcat output

```
04-10 19:44:52.815: D/AndroidRuntime(1794): Shutting down VM
04-10 19:44:52.815: W/dalvikvm(1794): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
04-10 19:44:52.835: E/AndroidRuntime(1794): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-10 19:44:52.835: E/AndroidRuntime(1794): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-10 19:44:52.835: E/AndroidRuntime(1794):     at sean.vieten.acm.Athletics$1.onClick(Athletics.java:66)
04-10 19:44:52.835: E/AndroidRuntime(1794):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
04-10 19:44:52.835: E/AndroidRuntime(1794):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
04-10 19:44:52.835: E/AndroidRuntime(1794):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-10 19:44:52.835: E/AndroidRuntime(1794):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-10 19:44:52.835: E/AndroidRuntime(1794):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-10 19:44:52.835: E/AndroidRuntime(1794):     at       android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-10 19:44:52.835: E/AndroidRuntime(1794):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-10 19:44:52.835: E/AndroidRuntime(1794):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-10 19:44:52.835: E/AndroidRuntime(1794):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-10 19:44:52.835: E/AndroidRuntime(1794):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-10 19:44:52.835: E/AndroidRuntime(1794):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Problem solved, it seems I had two onclick listeners matched up to the same button, so when I clicked the button multiple intents were created which explains the crash.  Very, very foolish error on my part.

Comment: post the `logcat` you get, when the program `FORCE CLOSES`.

Comment: Your missing " in getStringArrayExtra is a typo? Have you tried logging the values in the list?

Comment: ur code working i don know why not working work u , check here getStringArrayExtra("string");

Comment: check the stringarray in class A also

Comment: The string array works as expected in class A, yes the missing " was a typo... sorry.

Answer (score 1):

In Activity B use this.

```
 Intent intent= getIntent();

 theList[] = intent.getStringArrayExtra("string");
```

Comment: I had actually originally had that code before reducing it to what is in the original post, they both gave the same result.

Answer (score 1):

i got the same problem,in my case i use

```java
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>;
...
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("string",list.toArray());
...
String strs = intent.getStringArrayExtra("string");
```

i found that strs is allways null,because list.toArray returns an object array;so we should use an String array instead

```java
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>;
...
Intent intent = new Intent();
String[] strArr = new String[list.size()];
list.toArray(strArr);
intent.putExtra("string",strArr);
...
String strs = intent.getStringArrayExtra("string");
```

or you can get an ArrayList instead

```java
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("string", arrayList);
...
List<String>  list = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("string");
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Don't use `getApplicationContext()` use `Activity`'s context
2) Use more informational key name than "string"

Good luck

Comment: By the activities context i'd assume you mean classname.this?

and yes I understand that is a horrible name, just want ended up there through my trouble shooting process.  Thank you for pointing that out though.

Answer (score 0):

**Activity 1**

```
Bundle b=new Bundle();
b.putStringArray("strings", new String[]{"aaa","bbb"});
Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
intent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Activity 2**

```
 Intent intent=getIntent();
 Bundle b=intent.getExtras();
 String[] array=b.getStringArray("strings");
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I did like this

```
val arrayList = arrayListOf<String>()
arrayList.add("data")

Intent(applicationContext, MyService::class.java).apply {
    putExtra("myKey", arrayList)
}
```

in Service or Activity

```
val dataArray = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("myKey")!!
```